# add subLayer to a imageView.layer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, calayer

well I know that every imageViews have a layer (we can access it with :imageView.layer).I would like to use the layer of my `imageView` and add a subLayer to it's layer:`shapeLayer`(that is a CAShapeLayer) My code doesn't work, it doesn't show the shape layer!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
   [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

- (void)anotherMethod
{
   [imageView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

How can I solve this please ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[outputImage.layer insertSublayer:shapeLayer atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problem by using `UIView` below `UIImageView` and setting a layer to `UIView`. When you add a layer to `UIImageView` at index 0, your image will not be visible.

I have a `UIView` called `photoView`. It has a subview of class `UIImageView`, that has same bounds and has a **clear** background color. And I add a `gradientLayer` to `photoView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Adding gradient background to UIImageView
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.photoImageView.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor customUltraLightGrayColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor customUltraLightGrayColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor customDarkGrayColor].CGColor];
    gradientLayer.locations = @[@(0.0), @(0.6)];
    [self.photoView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

As a result I get this:

[image: Gradient background of UIImageView]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about just one UIImageView (imageView == outputImage ???)

```
//in another method:
{
    [imageView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer]; //Where is outputImage initialized?
}
```

Comment: I think the code is right. Could it be possible that the shape layer is empty / not existing (width or height == 0)? Try `[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer]`. Does something happen?

Comment: you are right when I do [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer] nothing happen. so how can i solve this please ?

Answer (score 0):

This could have several reasons, for example:

- Did you `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` (and / or `CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>` depending on what you are doing in the rest of your code)?
- You could have set a wrong `CGRectMake` when initializing the `CALayer` which is not inside your visible frame (Like `CGRectMake(5000,5000,...,...)`) or one of the `size` properties is `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the frame for layer: 
Follow the three steps

```
CALayer layerToBeAdded = [[CALayer alloc] init];
[layerToBeAdded setFrame:imgView.frame];
[imgView.layer addSublayer:layerToBeAdded];
```

**Instead of allocating CALayer, you can use `[imgView layer]`**

And to add image to layer do it like this

```
layerToBeAdded.contents = (id)imgXYZ.CGImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
CALayer *pulseLayer_ = [[CALayer layer] retain];
pulseLayer_.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
pulseLayer_.bounds = CGRectMake(0., 0., 80., 80.);
pulseLayer_.cornerRadius = 12.;
pulseLayer_.position = self.view.center;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:pulseLayer_];
CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageLayer.frame = pulseLayer_.bounds;
imageLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
imageLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"jacklogo.png"].CGImage;
imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
[pulseLayer_ addSublayer:imageLayer];
[pulseLayer_ setNeedsDisplay];
```