# How to create an overlay color with a gradient in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, cgcolor

Background info: I have a `UIImageView`. I have added an overlay colour on its image in the following way:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(initialImage.size);
[initialImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, initialImage.size.width, initialImage.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:alphaValue];
UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, initialImage.size.width, initialImage.size.height)];
[overlayColor setFill];
[path fillWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeMultiply alpha:1];
finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self setImage:finalImage];
```

I still want to add this as an overlay colour but I want it to have a gradient. I have been trying to figure out a way to do this but haven't really been successful. I guess, the approach of adding an overlay colour with a gradient is wrong? I'm not sure about how to do this. I have tried to add a `CGGradientLayer` as a `sublayer` to the `UIImageView` but it doesn't work.

I thought about adding a `UIView` and setting it's `backgroundColor` as the `overlayColor`and then adding a `CGGradientLayer` as `sublayer` of the `UIView` which is added as a `subview` to the `UIImageView` but, we are not supposed to add `subviews` to `UIImageViews`.

Can someone please help me with this? Maybe I should change my approach?

Pointing me in the right direction will be great as well!

I look forward to your responses and apologies if this post hasn't been entirely clear!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: Code for the `CGGradientLayer`

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.frame;

UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor colorFromHex:self.feedColor withAlpha:(alphaValue * 0.7)];
UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorFromHex:self.feedColor withAlpha:(alphaValue * 1.0)];

gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, (id)colorTwo.CGColor, nil];

[self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Did you insert your `CGGradientLayer` above the `UIImageView` layer?

Comment: Yes, I have just edited my post to show the code. Hope this is what you were asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a more dynamic approach, then I would subclass `CALayer` instead of `UIImageView`. Therefore you'd want something like this:

```
@interface gradientImageLayer : CALayer

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end

@implementation gradientImageLayer

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.opaque = YES; // Best for performance, but you if you want the layer to have transparency, then remove.

        UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo2.png"]; // Replace with your image

        self.frame = frame;

        self.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale;
        self.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)(i.CGImage);

        // Your code for the CAGradientLayer was indeed correct.
        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.frame = frame;

        // Add whatever colors you want here.
        UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.1];
        UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.2];

        gradient.colors = @[(id)colorOne.CGColor, (id)colorTwo.CGColor]; // Literals read far nicer than a clunky [NSArray arrayWith.... ]

        [self addSublayer:gradient];        
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

The downside to this approach is you are unable to apply different blend modes. The only solutions I've seen to applying a blend mode on a `CALayer` is through Core Graphics, but then you'd be better off with my original answer.

Comment: Okay I will implement this! Thank you very much for your reply!!

Answer (score 2):

I would just use Core Graphics in order to take your input image, apply a gradient overlay to it, and then pass it onto the `UIImageView`. Something like this should achieve the desired result:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithGradientOverlay:(UIImage *)sourceImage color1:(UIColor *)color1 color2:(UIColor *)color2 gradPointA:(CGPoint)pointA gradPointB:(CGPoint)pointB {

    CGSize size = sourceImage.size;

    // Start context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw source image into context
    CGContextDrawImage(c, (CGRect){CGPointZero, size}, sourceImage.CGImage);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat gradLocs[] = {0, 1};
    NSArray *colors = @[(id)color1.CGColor, (id)color2.CGColor];

    // Create a simple linear gradient with the colors provided.
    CGGradientRef grad = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, gradLocs);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Draw gradient with multiply blend mode over the source image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, grad, pointA, pointB, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(grad);

    // Grab resulting image from context
    UIImage *resultImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultImg;
}
```

This is where `sourceImage` is the input image, `color1` and `color2` are your gradient colors and `gradPointA` and `gradPointB` are your linear gradient end points (In Core Graphics coordinate system, bottom left is (0,0)).

This way you save having to mess about with layers. If you're frequently re-drawing with different colors, then you may want to take an approach that uses layers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am constantly changing the color and image. Would you say that I the CGGradientLayer code I'm using is correct? Should I just use it without doing the overlayColor processing?

Comment: It looks correct to me, but from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630869/add-sublayer-to-a-imageview-layer it seems that you can't add sublayers to a `UIImageView` either. You will probably have to add it to the superview's layer.

Comment: It has also occured to me to wonder, why are you using a `UIImageView`? Why not use a `CALayer` and set the `contents` property to your image? That way you could easily overlay a sublayer on it.

Comment: I am actually subclassing UIImageView. Do you think creating it as a subclass of CALayer is better?

Comment: I would, as it would remove the quirks that come with `UIImageView`. After all a `UIImageView` is just a container for an underlying `CALayer` with the image as the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the collaborative solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541153/ios-blend-mode-multiply/52081779#52081779)

This category allows you to add a Color Overlay or Gradient Color Overlay using any blend mode (multiply, normal, etc) and CoreGraphics

**Swift 4:**

```
extension UIImage {

    //creates a static image with a color of the requested size
    static func fromColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context?.fill(rect)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
    }

    func blendWithColorAndRect(blendMode: CGBlendMode, color: UIColor, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {

        let imageColor = UIImage.fromColor(color: color, size:self.size)

        let rectImage = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, true, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // fill the background with white so that translucent colors get lighter
        context!.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rectImage)

        self.draw(in: rectImage, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
        imageColor.draw(in: rect, blendMode: blendMode, alpha: 0.8)

        // grab the finished image and return it
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        //self.backgroundImageView.image = result
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result!

    }
    //creates a static image with a gradient of colors of the requested size
    static func fromGradient(colors: [UIColor], locations: [CGFloat], horizontal: Bool, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let cgColors = colors.map {$0.cgColor} as CFArray
        let grad = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: cgColors , locations: locations)

        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let endPoint = horizontal ? CGPoint(x: size.width, y: 0) : CGPoint(x: 0, y: size.height)

        context?.drawLinearGradient(grad!, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: .drawsAfterEndLocation)

        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
    }

    func blendWithGradientAndRect(blendMode: CGBlendMode, colors: [UIColor], locations: [CGFloat], horizontal: Bool = false, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {

        let imageColor = UIImage.fromGradient(colors: colors, locations: locations, horizontal: horizontal, size: size)

        let rectImage = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, true, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // fill the background with white so that translucent colors get lighter
        context!.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rectImage)

        self.draw(in: rectImage, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
        imageColor.draw(in: rect, blendMode: blendMode, alpha: alpha)

        // grab the finished image and return it
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        //self.backgroundImageView.image = result
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result!

    }
}
```

**Example Gradient:**

```
let  newImage = image.blendWithGradientAndRect(blendMode: .multiply,
                                           colors: [.red, .white],
                                           locations: [0, 1],
                                           horizontal: true,
                                           alpha: 0.8,
                                           rect: imageRect)
```

**Example Single Color:**

```
let newImage = image.blendWithColorAndRect(blendMode: .multiply, color: .red, rect: imageRect)
```

Comment: a bit late, but I'm using parts of your code. The problem that I'm having is that I'm currently using this on a custom `tableviewcell` during `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`, which makes the scrolling really jumpy. Because my cells are dynamic, I need to re-draw them, but I don't know if there's a better way to implement this without re-drawing the images every time. Any thoughts? Thanks